# How to fit a font size on each device in Main storyboard of iOS?

Tags: ios, css, fonts, storyboard

I want to adjust font size for each device. The UI is created for `iPhone 8`. So the font size is `14`. But other phones don't see all the letters because the screen is small. How do I adjust this?

**Main.storyboard**

[image: storyboard one]

[image: storyboard one_1]

https://useyourloaf.com/blog/size-classes/  <= I tried to solve the problem by referring to this site, but couldn't help me.

Comment: Have you enabled "Use Trait Variation" on your storyboard? Check the "Attributes Inspector Trait Variations" section of this article. https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Trait_Variations_to_Design_Adaptive_iOS_User_Interfaces#Attributes_Inspector_Trait_Variations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with storyboard. You only can with code, in your code you check device type using bounds of screen. And change font size for each screen size.

UPDATE:
You can try like this

```
let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
if screenWidth == 640 {
   // iPhone 4inch and 3.5inch. Smaller than iPhone 8
   // Call change font
}
```

Comment: If you can solve it by code, can you show it by code?

Comment: I can't solve it because I'm a beginner.

Comment: @iosbegindevel Check my update answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how do I change the font size?

Comment: @iosbegindevel If you want to change UILabel font. Just `yourLabelVar.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)` to set font size if 12

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'd like to ask you one more question. I tried to add a label to the text view. The label is obscured by a text view. How do I get this to look?

Comment: @iosbegindevel You should not add label inside UITextView. Please add label to same level as UITextView( is same superview with UITextView)